# Redirect not working with header("Location:

Tags: php, html, redirect, http-headers

I've searched but can't seem to figure this one out. I have a config.php which searches for an active session and if found passes the user through, if not it fowards to the login.php page. The config.php also grabs the orginal URL and posts to login.php so we can redirect them to the page they were going to originally.

From there it should be pretty simple, authenticate and then use the redirect variable to forward browser to original page. But it's not working like that. It forwards me back to the login.php and says "Object Moved". Its redirects if I put header("location: /index.php"); but not if I use the variable in the login.php like below.

Any help would be appreciated!

PHP (config.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
// put somewhere in a config file
define('SESSION_EXPIRE',3600); // in seconds

// check passage of time, force log-out session expire time
if(isset($_SESSION['last_activity']) && (time() - strtotime($_SESSION['last_activity']) >     SESSION_EXPIRE)) {
// destroy session
session_unset();
session_destroy();
}

// if user is logged in and unexpired, update activity
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
// user is logged in
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

// if user doesn't have session forward them to login page and post requested URL
if (!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '')) {
header ("Location: ../login.php?location=" . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
}
?>
```

PHP (login.php):

```
<?php
include("authenticate.php");

// check to see if user is logging out
if(isset($_GET['out'])) {
// destroy session
session_unset();
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION['user'],$_SESSION['access']);
session_destroy();
}
// get orginal URL from config.php
$url = $_GET['location'];

// check to see if login form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['userLogin'])){
// run information through authenticator
if(authenticate($_POST['userLogin'],$_POST['userPassword']))
{
    // authentication passed
    header("location:".$url);
    die();
} else {
    // authentication failed
    $error = 1;
}
}


// output logout success
if (isset($_GET['out'])) echo "Logout successful";
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
         <fieldset>
             <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="userLogin" type="Username" autofocus>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="userPassword" type="password" value="">
             </div>
      <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />

      </fieldset>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: is `session_start();` in login.php also?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No it is not.

Comment: it's required there too

Comment: @Fred-ii- not if it is in `authenticate.php`

Comment: Do you happen to be running PHP with IIS? I ask because I've only seen Object Moved in .NET projects I've worked on.

Comment: @David Yes thank you. It's in authenticate.php

Comment: @David You have a point there; seems like it is then.

Comment: @mikehomme yes it's PHP with IIS.

Comment: is `session_start()` in `authenticate.php` ? also work with `error_reporting(-1)` maybe there are some helpful error reported

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path?

Comment: @sking Yes session_start() is in authenticate.php. Only error I see is Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: @mikehomme Yes, I have tried header("location: index.php"); and it redirects there fine, but I want to redirect to the URL in the variable depending on how they got to the login.php. I know the variable is loaded because i'm outputting it to a div just to make sure it's correct.

Comment: are you saying that you know the location variable is loaded in the login.php script after the redirect from config.php?

Comment: @silversunhunter Yes, the config.php is posting correctly because I can output $url to a div in login.php.

Comment: But the problem is that after authentication it does not redirect to the $location ??

Comment: Isn't the header `Location: X` with a capital L and a space?

Comment: @silversunhunter the problem is it doesn't redirect to the header("location:".$url);

Comment: @Mgamerz Same thing even if I change to header("Location: " . $url);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove login.php from here: `action="login.php"` You're losing the $url variable because it's not being included in the GET after the page posts back to itself.

Comment: If there was a basket of cookies button I would totally send you some. Thanks again. Was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand your exact problem but if you are trying to redirect to $location and it is not going to the proper page or throwing an error then you may need to urldecode it before passing the variable.

in your config you encode the URI:

```
// if user doesn't have session forward them to login page and post requested URL
if (!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '')) {
    header ("Location: ../login.php?location=" . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
}
```

So in your Login decode it:

```
$url = urldecode($_GET['location']);
```

As mGamerz said make sure that your header has a capitol L and a space after the colon

```
header("Location: ".$url);
```

Comment: Added decode in my login.php, modified the header as you and mGamerz stated and still the same result. No foward.

Comment: @solar411 are you getting any output or error message?

Comment: It goes back to login.php and says Object Moved

This document may be found here

Comment: If I change it to header("Location: anything.html"); it redirects perfectly fine with anything inside the quotes.

Comment: For kicks, try this: header("location:" . $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/" . $url);

Comment: header("location:" . $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/" . $url); goes nowhere. Weird.

Comment: And the page is posting back to itself, and action="" in the form?

Comment: Yes, that's what it looks like.

Comment: Then I would try moving $url = $_GET['location'];  inside of your if statement for authentication.

Comment: Could you post the HTML for the form as well?

Comment: I just tried $url = urldecode($_GET['location']); in the if statement and same result. Will post form HTML.

Comment: Ok, well, what about adding header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); just above the redirect?